# Allow for formally flagging broken links in questions / answers

Tags: feature-request, flags, broken-link

This answer here has a broken link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2535051/521799

The standard procedure seems to be to comment on this answer for the author to correct the link. But then, I'll have to somehow track it in order to remove my obsolete comment, once the OP corrects the link.

Instead, it would be very useful if I could simply flag the question for a broken link. This flag would then send a message to the OP's inbox asking them to fix the link. If the OP doesn't fix (= edit or delete) the answer in about 1-2 weeks, this would become a regular moderator flag (or just a regular comment).

In addition to the OP seeing this, these questions / answers could also be featured in the review tab...

Some related meta questions:

- [Is it possible to automatically mark broken links?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69832/is-it-possible-to-automatically-mark-broken-links)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132503/show-which-links-are-invalid-broken
- [What should we do for questions with broken links that are still answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132008/what-should-we-do-for-questions-with-broken-links-that-are-still-answered)

Comment: FYI, I fixed the dead link. (So to the others, yes, it was really dead) :)

Comment: @Bart: Man, you see? Now I will have to remove my comment again and the OP has a useless message in the inbox! ;-) Thanks anyway for fixing it

Comment: As for a moderator flag, I'm not so sure. What could they do about it? If the answer purely relied on the link to be useful, then it wasn't really an answer to begin with.

Comment: @Bart: You're probably right. That would generate too much moderator work. Maybe it could be transformed into a regular comment...?